# To which complexity class does this language belong?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, complexity-classes

I was thinking about which class this language belongs:
$L =\{ \langle G,k \rangle \mid G $ is a graph, $k$ is a natural number and $k$ is the chromatic number of $G\}$

I thought of $L$ as (1) " there is no coloring of k-1 colors" and (2) "there is coloring of $k$ colors". Now, (1) is coNP and (2) is NP-complete so I assume that this language is neither in NP nor in coNP, but I didn't find to which class it belongs.
Any help will be welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is contained in [DP: Difference Polynomial-Time](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:D#dp), which is also [BH$_2$, the second level of the Boolean hierarchy](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:B#bh). This class is itself contained in $\Delta^\textrm{P}$, but that is believed to be a bigger class.

A language L is in DP if it is the intersection of a language L<sub>1</sub> in NP with a language L<sub>2</sub> in coNP, and so your example is clearly in DP.

Answer (score 19):

(as pointed out by Robin the problem is in DP...)

...and it is also DP-complete.

In fact, Jörg Rothe has shown that this even holds for fixed k=4: Jörg Rothe: Exact complexity of Exact-Four-Colorability. Inf. Process. Lett. (IPL) 87(1):7-12 (2003)

Comment: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0020-0190(03)00229-1 or see the preprint http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0109018